# Retrieving Pyomo solution without using for loop

Tags: pyomo

I am struggling to find an efficient way of retrieving the solution to an optimization problem. The solution consists of around 200K variables that I would like in a pandas DataFrame. After searching online the only approaches I found for accessing the variables was through a for loop which looks something like this:

```
instance = M.create_instance('input.dat') # reading in a datafile
results = opt.solve(instance, tee=True)
results.write()
instance.solutions.load_from(results)

for v in instance.component_objects(Var, active=True): 
    print ("Variable",v)
    varobject = getattr(instance, str(v))
    for index in varobject:
        print ("   ",index, varobject[index].value)
```

I know I can use this for loop to store them in a dataframe but this is pretty inefficient. 
I found out how to access the indexes by using

```
import pandas as pd
index = pd.DataFrame(instance.component_objects(Var, active=True))
```

But I dont know how to get the solution

Comment: You can check the variables individually via, `model.some_var.pprint()`. You need to add `.pprint()` to the end then you may see the variables with all of their indices.

Answer (score 5):

There is actually a very simple and elegant solution, using the method `pandas.DataFrame.from_dict` combined with the `Var.extract_values()` method.

```py
from pyomo.environ import *
import pandas as pd
m = ConcreteModel()
m.N = RangeSet(5)
m.x = Var(m.N, rule=lambda _, el: el**2)  # x = [1,4,9,16,25]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(m.x.extract_values(), orient='index', columns=[str(m.x)])
print(df)
```

yields

```
    x
1   1
2   4
3   9
4  16
5  25
```

Note that for `Var` we can use both `get_values()` and `extract_values()`, they seem to do the same. For `Param` there is only `extract_values()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! what about extraction of lagrange multipliers ?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can use `instance.some_var.pprint()` to print it on the screen.
But if you have a variable indexed by a large set. You can also write it to a
seperate file. The following code writes the result to a .txt file:

```
f = open('Result.txt', 'a')
instance.some_var.pprint(f)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as Jasper and tried the suggested solutions. By doing so I noticed, that the part writing the results takes most time. Maybe this is also true in Jasper's case.

```
results.write()
instance.solutions.load_from(results)
```

So I suggest to surpress this two lines if you can do so. Maybe someone has a suggestions how to speed this up? Or an alternative method.

Also I saw that in this post (Pyomo: Save results to CSV files) The "for loop" method is recomanded. A pyomo developer states:"I think it's possible in option 2 for the indices and the variable slice to be iterated over in a different order which would invalidate your resulting array."

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity of code and to largely avoid for-loops, I found the `pyomoio` module in the [urbs project](https://github.com/tum-ens/urbs/blob/master/urbs/pyomoio.py), which has taken over the slightly deprecated code of [pandaspyomo.py](https://github.com/ojdo/python-tools/blob/master/pandaspyomo.py). It relies on each pyomo object's `iteritem()` method, and handles multiple dimensions elegantly. It can extract sets, parameters, variables as pandas objects.

If I set up a small pyomo model

```py
from pyomo.environ import *
import pyomoio as po
import pandas as pd

# Define a model with 200k values
m = ConcreteModel()
m.ix = RangeSet(200000)
def idem(model, i):
    return i
m.a = Param(m.ix, rule=idem)
```

I can read in the parameter with just one line of code

```py
%%timeit
a_po = po.get_entity(m, 'a')

# 110 ms ± 1.88 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

However, if I compare it to the approach in the original question, it is *not* faster, even a little slower:

```py
%%timeit
val = []
ix = []
varobject = getattr(m, 'a')
for index in varobject:
    ix.append(index)
    val.append(varobject[index])
a = pd.Series(index=ix, data=val)
# 92.5 ms ± 1.57 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```